# How read value from uri key json

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

i have this object

```
{
  'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier': '918312asdasc812',
  'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name': 'Login1',
  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role': 'User'
}
```

How read value for key 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier'?

Solution:

```
obj['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier']
```

Comment: Did you try `obj['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier']`?

Comment: @Andy thx it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Andy

Solution:

```
obj['http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier']
```

Answer (score 1):

to access key, value pairs in an object you can use `Object.entries(yourObjName)`.

```
foo = {
  'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier': '918312asdasc812',
  'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name': 'Login1',
  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role': 'User'
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(foo)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

read more information on [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the values of the object in an array and access the array:

```
const object1 = {
     'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier': '918312asdasc812',
      'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name': 'Login1',
      'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role': 'User'
    };
    
    const arr = (Object.values(object1));
    console.log(arr[0]);
```